# I'm getting errors about malformed entries

Tags: linux, linux-mint, apt

When I do `sudo apt update` I get this error:

```
E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list (Component) 
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

I am on Linux Mint 21 Cinnamon.

The contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list`:

```
deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic
main
```

I'm very new to Linux and I do not understand what this mean or how I may fix it.

Comment: Is that `main` on a line by itself?

Comment: yes I think so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is most likely due to a malformed entry in the `apt` command's source listings, as indicated by the error message.  There seems to be a stray newline character breaking a line in an unfortunate way, possibly due to a copy-and-paste mishap.

Removing the newline so that the complete file reads

```
deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main
```

... should solve the issue.

Comment: Thank you, It worked.